# Multiplying Two Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I perform operations such as Multiplying and Subtracting two columns in SQL Server?

```
Payment
PK - PaymentID
FK - PaymentTypeID
FK - OccupiedApartmentID
   **- InitalPayment
   - MonthlyRate
   - Balance**
   - PaymentDate
```

Answer (score 76):

In a query you can just do something like:

```
SELECT ColumnA * ColumnB FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT ColumnA - ColumnB FROM table
```

You can also create computed columns in your table where you can permanently use your formula.

Answer (score 21):

```
select InitialPayment * MonthlyPayRate as SomeRandomCalculation from Payment
```

Answer (score 6):

**Syntax:**

```
SELECT <Expression>[Arithmetic_Operator]<expression>...
 FROM [Table_Name] 
 WHERE [expression];
```

1. **Expression** : Expression made up of a single constant, variable, scalar function, or column name and can also be the pieces of a SQL query that compare values against other values or perform arithmetic calculations.
2. **Arithmetic_Operator** : Plus(+), minus(-), multiply(*), and divide(/).
3. **Table_Name** : Name of the table.

Answer (score 1):

This code is used to multiply the values of one column

```
select exp(sum(log(column))) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select InitialPayment * MonthlyRate as MultiplyingCalculation,
InitialPayment - MonthlyRate as SubtractingCalculation
 from Payment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query:

for multiplication

```
Select columnA * cloumnB as MultiplyResult from TableName
```

for subtraction

```
Select columnA - cloumnB as SubtractionResult from TableName
```