# Multiply columns for currency exchange

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two columns in my MySQL table `total` and `dollars`. I need to convert my dollars into rupees and store it in my `total` field. Can I multiply live dollar rates and store the result?

I need a SQL query for a mathematical function which is like this:

```
total = dollars * current_dollar_rate_in_rupees
```

Can I make this conversion dynamic? If so how and what would be my SQL query?

Comment: What have you tried so far? `UPDATE table SET total = dollars * current_dollar_rate_in_rupees` ? OR, you can even `SELECT dollars * current_dollar_rate_in_rupees AS total FROM table` to make the conversion every time you run a select query...

Comment: How do I get the live dollar rate in rupees? It keeps changing so how can I assign live values to the variable current_dollar_rate_in_rupees?

Comment: MySQL does not know *current_dollar_rate_in_rupees*. You need to figure out some web-service to get updated information into your database on a timed (daily/hourly/etc) basis. And then use that information to calculate prices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Multiplying Two Columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536996/multiplying-two-columns-in-sql-server)

So just store the value that is giving by this query in your database as 'total'

```
SELECT dollars * current_dollar_rate_in_rupees from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store conversion  result into `total` field with this query:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `total` = `dollars` * <current_dollar_rate_in_rupees>;
```